# Speed of Pascal CUDA8 1080Ti unified memory

Tags: cuda, openacc

Thanks to the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43746493/ta-teslamanagedcuda8-but-cumemallocmanaged-returned-error-2-out-of-memory) yesterday, I think I now have a correct basic test of unified memory using Pascal 1080Ti. It allocates a 50GB single dimension array and adds it up. If I understand correctly, it should be memory bound since this test is so simple (adding integers). However, it takes 24 seconds equating to about 2GB/s. When I run the CUDA8 bandwidthTest I see higher rates: 11.7GB/s pinned and 8.5GB/s pageable.

Is there any way to get the test to run faster than 24 seconds?

Here's the full test code :

```
$ cat firstAcc.c 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <openacc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define GB 50

static double wallclock()
{
  double ans = 0;
  struct timespec tp;
  if (0==clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp))
      ans = (double) tp.tv_sec + 1e-9 * (double) tp.tv_nsec;
  return ans;
}

int main()
{
  int *a;

  size_t n = (size_t)GB*1024*1024*1024/sizeof(int);
  size_t s = n * sizeof(int);
  printf("n = %lu, GB = %.3f\n", n, (double)s/(1024*1024*1024));
  a = (int *)malloc(s);
  if (!a) { printf("Failed to malloc.\n"); return 1; }

  setbuf(stdout, NULL);
  double t0 = wallclock();
  printf("Initializing ... ");
  for (long i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    a[i] = i%7-3;
  }
  double t1 = wallclock();
  printf("done in %f (single CPU thread)\n", t1-t0);
  t0=t1;

  int sum=0.0;
  #pragma acc parallel loop reduction (+:sum)
  for (long i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    sum+=a[i];
  }
  t1 = wallclock();
  printf("Sum is %d and it took %f\n", sum, t1-t0);
  free(a);
  return 0;
}
```

I compile it as follows :

```
$ pgcc -fast -acc -ta=tesla:managed:cc60 -Minfo=accel firstAcc.c
main:
     40, Accelerator kernel generated
         Generating Tesla code
         40, Generating reduction(+:sum)
         41, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(128) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
     40, Generating implicit copyin(a[:13421772800])
```

Then I run it twice :

```
$ ./a.out
n = 13421772800, GB = 50.000
Initializing ... done in 36.082607 (single CPU thread)
Sum is -5 and it took 23.902612
$ ./a.out
n = 13421772800, GB = 50.000
Initializing ... done in 36.001578 (single CPU thread)
Sum is -5 and it took 24.180615
```

The result (-5) is correct as I setup the data that way. The numbers are repeated sequences of 7 integers -3:+3 which when summed all cancel out other than the remainder of 2 at the end (-3 -2 = -5).

The bandwidthTest (CUDA 8 samples/1_Utilities) result for pageable is :

```
$ ./bandwidthTest --memory=pageable
[CUDA Bandwidth Test] - Starting...
Running on...

 Device 0: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti
 Quick Mode

 Host to Device Bandwidth, 1 Device(s)
 PAGEABLE Memory Transfers
   Transfer Size (Bytes)        Bandwidth(MB/s)
   33554432                     8576.7

 Device to Host Bandwidth, 1 Device(s)
 PAGEABLE Memory Transfers
   Transfer Size (Bytes)        Bandwidth(MB/s)
   33554432                     11474.3

 Device to Device Bandwidth, 1 Device(s)
 PAGEABLE Memory Transfers
   Transfer Size (Bytes)        Bandwidth(MB/s)
   33554432                     345412.1

Result = PASS

NOTE: The CUDA Samples are not meant for performance measurements. Results may vary when GPU Boost is enabled.
```

I see that note. But what should I use instead? Do these measurements seem in the right ballpark?

Is there anything that can be done to make the test run in more like 6 seconds (50GB / 8.5GB/s) rather than 25s?

The result with --mode=shmoo actually shows pageable reaching a higher rate: 11GB/s.

```
$ ./bandwidthTest --memory=pageable --mode=shmoo
[CUDA Bandwidth Test] - Starting...
Running on...

 Device 0: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti
 Shmoo Mode

.................................................................................
 Host to Device Bandwidth, 1 Device(s)
 PAGEABLE Memory Transfers
   Transfer Size (Bytes)        Bandwidth(MB/s)
   1024                         160.3
   2048                         302.1
   3072                         439.2
   4096                         538.4
   5120                         604.6
   6144                         765.3
   7168                         875.0
   8192                         979.2
   9216                         1187.3
   10240                        1270.6
   11264                        1335.0
   12288                        1449.3
   13312                        1579.6
   14336                        1622.2
   15360                        1836.0
   16384                        1995.0
   17408                        2133.0
   18432                        2189.8
   19456                        2289.2
   20480                        2369.7
   22528                        2525.8
   24576                        2625.8
   26624                        2766.0
   28672                        2614.4
   30720                        2895.8
   32768                        3050.5
   34816                        3151.1
   36864                        3263.8
   38912                        3339.2
   40960                        3395.6
   43008                        3488.4
   45056                        3557.0
   47104                        3642.1
   49152                        3658.5
   51200                        3736.9
   61440                        4040.4
   71680                        4076.9
   81920                        4310.3
   92160                        4522.6
   102400                       4668.5
   204800                       5461.5
   307200                       5820.7
   409600                       6003.3
   512000                       6153.8
   614400                       6232.5
   716800                       6285.9
   819200                       6368.9
   921600                       6409.3
   1024000                      6442.5
   1126400                      6572.3
   2174976                      8239.3
   3223552                      9041.6
   4272128                      9524.2
   5320704                      9824.5
   6369280                      10065.2
   7417856                      10221.2
   8466432                      10355.7
   9515008                      10452.8
   10563584                     10553.9
   11612160                     10613.1
   12660736                     10680.3
   13709312                     10728.1
   14757888                     10763.8
   15806464                     10804.4
   16855040                     10838.1
   18952192                     10820.9
   21049344                     10949.4
   23146496                     10990.7
   25243648                     11021.6
   27340800                     11028.8
   29437952                     11083.2
   31535104                     11098.9
   33632256                     10993.3
   37826560                     10616.5
   42020864                     10375.5
   46215168                     10186.1
   50409472                     10085.4
   54603776                     10013.9
   58798080                     10004.8
   62992384                     9998.6
   67186688                     10006.4
```

Thanks in advance.

```
$ pgcc -V
pgcc 17.4-0 64-bit target on x86-64 Linux -tp haswell 
PGI Compilers and Tools
Copyright (c) 2017, NVIDIA CORPORATION.  All rights reserved.

$ cat /usr/local/cuda-8.0/version.txt 
CUDA Version 8.0.61
```

Comment: probably not. unified memory is supposed to be convenient. it isn't fast

Comment: @talonmies That was unified memory of old, though, no? Isn't Pascal a hardware page-fault and since this test is perfectly page efficient (it's just a contiguous sweep) shouldn't it approach bus speeds?

Comment: I think you are expecting too much on multiple levels. For a start, I wouldn't expect `-ta=tesla:managed` to rewrite your explicit `malloc()` call to use CUDA managed memory instead.

Comment: @tera Why don't you expect that? I know it's a beta feature but the manual does say it does that and the people who answered the linked question raised other concerns but not that.  If you don't expect `:managed` to do that, what do you expect it to do?

Comment: I stand corrected, However see my comment on the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43770299/1662425).

Comment: Have you run nvprof on your test to see which page migrations occur ? It might be that the `-ta=tesla:managed:cc60` flag actually results in more paging than what you would expect.

Answer (score 5):

The page faulting process is clearly more complicated than a pure copy of data.  As a result, when you drive data to the GPU by page-faulting, it cannot compete performance-wise with a pure copy of the data.

Page faulting essentially introduces another kind of latency for the GPU to deal with.  The GPU is a latency-hiding machine, but it needs for the programmer to give it the opportunity to hide latency.  This can be roughly described as exposing enough parallel work.

On the surface of it, you seem to have exposed a lot of parallel work (~12B elements in your dataset).  But the work intensity per byte or element retrieved is quite small, so as a result the GPU still has limited opportunity to hide the latency associated with page-faulting here.  Stated another way, the GPU has an instantaneous capacity to perform latency hiding based on the maximum complement of threads that can be in flight on that GPU (upper bound: 2048 * # of SMs), and the work exposed in each thread.  Unfortunately, the work exposed in each thread in your example could be trivially small - a single addition, basically.

One of the ways to help with GPU latency hiding is increasing the work per thread, and there are various techniques to do this.  A good starting point would be to choose an algorithm (if possible) that has a high compute complexity.  Matrix-matrix multiply is the classical example of large compute complexity per element of data.

Some suggestions in this case would be to recognize that what you are trying to do is quite orderly, and therefore not that difficult to manage from a programming point of view, by breaking up the work into pieces and managing the data transfer yourself.  This will allow you to achieve the full bandwidth of the link for data transfer operations, achieve approximately full utilization of the host->device bandwidth, and (to a very small extent for this example) overlap of copy and compute.  For such a straightforward and easily decomposable problem such as this, it makes sense for the programmer *not* to use UM/oversubscription/page-faulting.

The place where this methodology (UM/oversubscription/page-faulting) may shine, for example, would be an algorithm where it's difficult for the programmer to predict the access pattern ahead of time.  Traversal of a large graph (which cannot all be in GPU memory at once) might be an example.  If you had a graph traversal problem with a large amount of work for each edge traversal, then the cost as you page-fault hopping node-to-node in the graph might not be a big deal, and simplification of the programming effort (not having to manage graph data movement explicitly) might be worth the cost.

Regarding pre-fetching, it's questionable, whether it would be of much use here, even if it were available.  Prefetching still essentially depends on having *something else to do* while the prefetch request is in flight.  When you have such a low amount of work per data item to be processed, it's not clear that a clever prefetching scheme would really provide much benefit for this example.  We can imagine possibly clever, complicated prefetching strategies, but such effort is probably better spent just crafting a partitioned explicit data transfer system for such a problem as this.

Answer (score 2):

In this blogpost from Nov 2013: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/unified-memory-in-cuda-6/ NVIDIA writes

> An important point is that **a carefully tuned CUDA program that uses streams and cudaMemcpyAsync** to efficiently overlap execution with data transfers **may very well perform better than a CUDA program that only uses Unified Memory**. Understandably so: the CUDA runtime never has as much information as the programmer does about where data is needed and when! CUDA programmers still have access to explicit device memory allocation and asynchronous memory copies to optimize data management and CPU-GPU concurrency. Unified Memory is first and foremost a productivity feature that provides a smoother on-ramp to parallel computing, without taking away any of CUDA’s features for power users.

Also in March 2014: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cudacasts-episode-18-cuda-6-0-unified-memory/

> CUDA 6 introduces Unified Memory, which dramatically simplifies memory management for GPU computing. Now you can focus on writing parallel kernels when porting code to the GPU, and **memory management becomes an optimization.**

Now, in CUDA 8 there were some improvements to Unified Memory mechanism https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-8-features-revealed/. In particular, they say:

> An important point is that CUDA programmers still have the tools they need to explicitly optimize data management and CPU-GPU concurrency where necessary: CUDA 8 introduces useful APIs for providing the runtime with memory usage hints (cudaMemAdvise()) and for explicit prefetching (cudaMemPrefetchAsync()). These tools allow the same capabilities as explicit memory copy and pinning APIs without reverting to the limitations of explicit GPU memory allocation.

So it appears that your example may be sped up using `cudaMemAdvise()` / `cudaMemPrefetch()`. However even with this, explicit memory management may still have a performance edge.

Added by OP :

> Performance through data locality
>   By migrating data on demand between the CPU and GPU, Unified Memory can offer the performance of local data on the GPU, while providing the ease of use of globally shared data. The complexity of this functionality is kept under the covers of the CUDA driver and runtime, ensuring that application code is simpler to write. The point of migration is to achieve full bandwidth from each processor; the 750 GB/s of HBM2 memory bandwidth is vital to feeding the compute throughput of a GP100 GPU. With page faulting on GP100, locality can be ensured even for programs with sparse data access, where the pages accessed by the CPU or GPU cannot be known ahead of time, and where the CPU and GPU access parts of the same array allocations simultaneously.

and

> Pascal also improves support for Unified Memory thanks to a larger virtual address space and **a new page migration engine, enabling higher performance, oversubscription of GPU memory,** and system-wide atomic memory operations.

Comment: Yes the last, most recent article is the most relevant since unified memory has improved over time.  I've edited in a paragraph from that article.  I wonder :  is there a big difference between Pascal P100 and Pascal 1080Ti with respect to the hardware page-faulting?

Comment: I thought (new) Pascal CUDA8 == hardware page fault unified memory.   Maybe not.  Maybe GP100 or P100 == hardware page fault and Pascal 1080Ti doesn't have it.  Or maybe there is a hardware page fault on 1080Ti but my expectations of it are too high.  The test is a perfectly contiguous sweep of the 50GB so the page-fault mechanism should work quite well for this test.

Comment: Yes, CUDA 8 on Pascal hardware implements page faults. But (unlike e.g. mapping a file into host memory) I don't think it currently implements prefetching on sequential access. Note that [cudaMemAdvise()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ge37112fc1ac88d0f6bab7a945e48760a) has no option to indicate sequential access, like e.g. the `MADV_SEQUENTIAL` argument to Linux/Posix [madvise()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise).

Comment: Your best bet probably is to issue a [cudaMemPrefetchAsync()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-tuning-prefetch) call before the kernel and hope that it happens to run correlated to the kernel. However I don't know if it has any effect on oversubscribed memory at all.

Comment: Thanks @tera very helpful.  Yes I'm familiar with madvise() and MADV_SEQUENTIAL so this comparison is very helpful.  It's good to know my 1080Ti indeed has hardware page-fault but it doesn't have prefetch.  I searched a long time online today and couldn't find this info anywhere!  Thanks.